# Effect of Frequently executing dumpsys on the Android system

Tags: android, linux, memory-management, sampling

I execute `dumpsys meminfo` every 2 seconds to sample memory usage of particular Android applications. Sometimes, the application (or even the emulator) crashes while the application is doing dumb things (e.g., rotate the screen back and forth). So, I want to understand how does "executing `dumpsys meminfo` frequently" affect the state of the whole system.

Answer (score 1):

I have a memory monitoring script that executes dumpsys meminfo a couple times a second and writes the info to a file and it almost never crashes, but I always test using physical devices.

It may be that your emulator just doesn't run fast enough to handle it. Android emulators are incredibly slow.